# I can't find the community console in AEM 6.0

Tags: aem

I would like to moderate the user rating (deleting/changing rating). I have read here http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/social_communities/community_console.html that this can be done with the `Community Console`. Where to find the community console in AEM 6.0? It is not available in AEM WCM toolbaar see the screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you dont have the permissions to access to community console, you can try accessing directly from the url in this case is:
localhost:port/socoadmin
regards

Comment: I am signed in as admin. accessing the direct url http://localhost:4502/socoadmin forwards me to Error page 500

Answer (score 0):

What version are you exactly using? In AEM Communities **6.1**, the Communities console, available from the main console of AEM, has expanded from providing moderation of user generated content (UGC) to providing access to administrative tasks such as creating a Community Site using a wizard, managing Community Site Templates, managing users (community members), and configuring the default common store for UGC.

In the author environment, after signing in with administrator privileges, the Communities menu is available from the main menu and provides access to the following consoles through the visible sub-menus :

[image]